# Flutter: How to send notifications to users when a document with specific field values is created. (how to subscribe to topic with condition)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to add a "Notify me" function in my flutter app where the user enters a date and other values so when a document is created with those values, the user can get a notification. I'm unable to add any conditions in `fcm.subscribeToTopic();`.TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Subscriptions to a topic are unconditional. The simplest way I can think of to implement this use-case is to create topics that contain the specific conditions that you are interested in, like `date_20210823_value_yourvalue`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cloud function and deploy it to firebase Functions, and in that function specify the path of collection (in which your document is creating) and it will trigger when a new document is created (write function for that. [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTq4KJG5quU) ). in order to send notifications to that user store that user's device Token. you can find [cloud Firestore Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#function_triggers) here.

some articles that help: [firebase tiggers](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-firebase-cloud-functions-and-triggers-%EF%B8%8F-85a8fe89be3c)